# Change lcd density with adb (Build.prop)

Tags: java, android, adb

I was messing around with my devices LCD Density, then I set it to 1000 to see what it was like. At this point it wasn't a big deal until i put my phone to sleep then tried to unlock it. Problem is the top bit of the pin is missing so I cannot enter the pattern.

So my question is. Is there any way I can change the density of my screen using adb?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is **not about programming**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
adb shell
su
mount -o rw,remount /system
cd /system
vi build.prop
```

find and change line with ro.sf.lcd_density and save ( learn how to vi editor :P )

reboot

Comment: Thanks, I know how to edit stuff. I ended up doing what you said anyways ahaha. Thanks though.!